# React native: header styles in navigationOptions not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am fairly new to react-native. I am trying to set some global header styles for my app, but it's not working

`route.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import SplashScreen from '../screens/SplashScreen';
import CalendarScreeen from '../screens/CalendarScreen';

const NavStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Splash: {
            screen: SplashScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                header: null
            },
        },
        Calendar: {
            screen: CalendarScreeen,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'Calendar',
            },
        },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Calendar',
        navigationOptions: {
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#28F1A6',
                elevation: 0,
                shadowOpacity: 0
            },
            headerTintColor: '#333333',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: '#ffffff'
            }
        }
       
    }

);

const Routes = createAppContainer(NavStack);
export default Routes;
```

Now, I am aware that I can do something like this in my class component

```
static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Chat',
  headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'red' },
  headerTitleStyle: { color: 'green' },
}
```

as it is mentioned in here [possible alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855660/react-native-change-react-navigation-header-styling)

but I want to achieve the same from my `route.js`

I also tried `defaultNavigationOptions` like its mentioned in [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html)

But no luck!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you are using react navigation version 3. If so **navigationOptions** is changed to **defaultNavigationOptions**.

```
{
        initialRouteName: 'Calendar',
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#28F1A6',
                elevation: 0,
                shadowOpacity: 0
            },
            headerTintColor: '#333333',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: '#ffffff'
            }
        }

}
```

It should work. https://snack.expo.io/ByGrHdAC7

Comment: oh, yea. this works fine. thanks. I might have done some stupid typo earlier when I had tried this.

Comment: Default navigation options are not working for me, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `defaultNavigationOptions`.

Admittedly, they didn't even mention that they changed it between v2 and v3 in the docs!

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html

Answer (score 2):

to setup custom react react navigation you need first defined **option.navigations** or **option.defaultNavigationOptions** in your App.js

App.js

```
 <Stack.Screen
                 name="ListeMedocItemScreen"
                 component={ListeMedocItemScreen}
                 options={ListeMedocItemScreen.defaultNavigationOptions} // ListeMedocItemScreen.navigationOptions

  />
```

then  in your conponents  page

if you use hooks

```
const ListeMedocItem = (props) =>{
  //some component
}


ListeMedocItem.defaultNavigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {

  return {
    title: 'My home',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },

 }}
```

or if you use React.Components

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    //return header with Custom View which will replace the original header 
    return {
      header: (
        <View
          style={{
            height: 45,
            marginTop: 20,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              color: 'white',
              textAlign: 'center',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              fontSize: 18,
            }}>
            This is Custom Header
          </Text>
        </View>
      ),
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just simply change your `navigationOptions`  to `defaultNavigationOptions`** **and it will work fine**

Thankx!

Answer (score -2):

`elevation: 0` in Android 10 doesnt work. Others Android version it works.
It is changes to transparent header.

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).